# SharePointContextFilter is gone in new app

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2013, and I have created a new sharepoint 2013 app.  It creates the app and the app web project in asp.net mvc, however it does not compile after creation mainly 2 problems:

```
1. SharePointContextFilter class is not there.
```

2nd. When I try to add AppForSharepointWebToolkit via nuget I get this error:

```
Installing 'AppForSharePointWebToolkit 3.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'AppForSharePointWebToolkit 3.0.1'.
Adding 'AppForSharePointWebToolkit 3.0.1' to Contoso.Apps.Helpdesk2Web.
Executing script file 'c:\users\xx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Contoso.Apps.Helpdesk1\packages\AppForSharePointWebToolkit.3.0.1\Tools\uninstall.ps1'.
Uninstalling 'AppForSharePointWebToolkit 3.0.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'AppForSharePointWebToolkit 3.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

Please note I am trying to create an app for sharepoint online and I dont have sharepoint on this machine which of course is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the readers, in case somebody experience it again. this happens when you dont restart your pc after installing vs 2013, weird behavior indeed, but after restarting it, the sharepoint contexfilter is created and solution builds